# groupBy and sum view in laravel

Tags: laravel, group-by, sum, laravel-blade

This is my controller

```
public function index()
{
    $students = Student::all();
    $users = auth()->user();
    $savings = Saving::where('user_id', '=', $users->id)->get();
    $saving = Saving::groupBy('user_id')
        ->selectRaw('sum(paid) as sum, user_id')
        ->pluck('sum','user_id');
    dd($saving);

    return view('pages.dashboard.siswa.saving.index', [
        'saving' => $saving
    ],

     compact('students', 'savings'));
}
```

this is my dd

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1353 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    1 => 30.0
    2 => 90.0
  ]
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}
```

and this is my blade view

```html
@foreach ($savings as $saving)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $saving->student->name }}</td>
        <td>Rp. {{ number_format($saving->paid, 2) }}</td>
        <td>Rp. {{ number_format($saving->sum('paid'), 2) }}</td>
        <td>
            <div class="table-data-feature">
            <a href="{{ route('dashboard.saving.edit', $saving->id) }}"><button class="item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit">
            <i class="zmdi zmdi-edit"></i>
            </button></a>
            <form class="inline" action= {{ route('dashboard.saving.destroy', $saving->id)  }} method="POST">
                 csrf
                 method('delete')
                 <button class="item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete">
                 <i class="zmdi zmdi-delete"></i>
                 </button>
             </form>
             </div>
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr class="spacer"></tr>
 endforeach
```

This is my schema

```
Schema::create('savings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('student_id');
            $table->foreignId('user_id');
            $table->date('date');
            $table->string('day');
            $table->string('paid');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

I was try to sum the `paid` column, I can sum for all user. What I want to know is how can I only show the `paid` value with column `user_id`? Like when `user_id = 1` access it, only show `paid` value for `user_id = 1`, not for the others. Thanks

Comment: show your schema (table columns), include it in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was try to sum the paid column, I can sum for all user. What I want to know is how can I only show the paid value with column user_id? Like when user_id = 1 access it, only show paid value for user_id = 1, not for the others. Thanks

From what I understand, you want to get the paid records for specific users and sum it up.

In your controller

```
public function index() {
    $totalSavings = auth()->user()->savings()->sum('paid');
    // or
    $userId = 1;
    $totalSavings = User::where('user_id', $userId)->savings()->sum('paid');
    // or
    $totalSavings = Savings::where('user_id', $userId)->sum('paid');

    return view('pages.dashboard.siswa.saving.index', [
        'totalSavings ' => $totalSavings 
    ],
}
```

in your User eloquent model

```
// User.php

public function savings() {
    return $this->hasMany(Savings::class);
}
```

in your Savings eloquent model

```
// Savings.php

public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

and in your blade view

```
<h1>{{ $totalSavings }}</h1>
```

---

But if you want to sum all paid records and show it beside every user, do this.

In your controller

```
public function index() {
    $savings = Savings::with('user')->withSum('savings', 'paid')->get();

    return view('pages.dashboard.siswa.saving.index', [
        'savings ' => $savings
    ],
}
```

in your User eloquent model

```
// User.php

public function savings() {
    return $this->hasMany(Savings::class);
}
```

in your Savings eloquent model

```
// Savings.php

public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

and in your blade view

```
@forelse ($savings as $saving)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $saving->user->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $saving->savings_sum_paid }}</td>
    </tr>
@empty
@endforelse
```

**NOTE:** You need to use an integer in your `paid` column.

```
// Change this line
$table->string('paid');

// To
$table->integer('paid');
```